# Proof: Derivative of $(-1)^{x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, complex-numbers

The derivative for $(-1)^{x}$ is 
\begin{equation}
\frac d{dx}\left[(-1)^x\right]=i\pi(-1)^{x}
\end{equation}
But why?

What happens with higher order derivatives?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $i\pi$ is constant, correct?

Comment: Do you have a reference for your formula? Is the function you are considering a function from the real numbers to the real numbers? What is your definition of $\frac{d}{dx}$?

Comment: The expression $(-1)^x$ is not defined in general.  You can interpret it to mean $e^{ \pi x i}$, and the formula follows from that.  But you could just as easily assume that it means $e^{3 \pi  x i}$ which has the derivative $3 \pi ie^{3 \pi  x i}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since
$$(-1)^{x}=(e^{i\pi})^x=e^{i\pi x}$$

We have
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}\left((-1)^{x}\right)=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(e^{i\pi x}\right)=i\pi e^{i\pi x}=i\pi(-1)^{x}
$$
For higher order derivatives
$$
\dfrac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}\left((-1)^{x}\right)=(i\pi)^n(-1)^{x}
$$

Comment: I don't get it. How is eiπx = -1?

Comment: @AkshatTripathi That's a pretty famous result in calculus, actually. Though I see why you're confused — How do you multiply something by itself an imaginary amount of times? The proof is too long to write in a comment, but trust us that the equation makes sense and is true.

Comment: @AkshatTripathi It's not that $e^{i \pi x} = -1$ but that $e^{i \pi} = -1$. By [Euler formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), we have: $$e^{\theta i} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta,$$ plugging in $\theta = \pi$ we get the desired result.

Comment: All right, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Mistake 1: The function $(-1)^x$ is not well-defined, even if $x$ is a complex number.

Mistake 2: You cannot say $\left( e^{\pi i} \right)^x = e^{\pi i x}$. The multiplication of exponent rule does not extend to complex numbers. Indeed, otherwise you have problems like $1^{\pi} = e^{2\pi^2 i}$, which is clearly false.

Comment: Possibly relevant: Wolfram Alpha interprets $(-1)^x$ to mean $e^{\pi ix}$.

Answer (score 2):

We have that $e^{i\pi}=-1$, so $(-1)^x=e^{i\pi x}$, therefore $\frac{d}{dx}e^{i\pi x}=i\pi e^{i\pi x}=i\pi (-1)^x$.

It's easy to see that $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(-1)^x=(i\pi)^n(-1)^x$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe the function $w=(-1)^z$ This is equivalent to $w=e^{z\ln(-1)}$ Now, recalling that the logarithm is a multivalued function, $$\ln(-1)=\ln\vert(-1)\vert +i\arg(-1)=i(\pi+2\pi n)$$We see that $(-1)^z$ Is equivalent to $w=e^{i\pi (2n+1)z}$ For all integers $n$. This means, except in special cases, that $(-1)^z$ has an infinite number of complex values. If we choose to let n be constant, and define $(-1)^z$ as the resulting single valued function, the complex derivative is equal to$$ i\pi (2n+1)e^{i\pi (2n+1)z}$$